# Google Analytics tracking by previous session activity

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

One of my managers has asked if it's possible to see how many users are returning to our website after having previously visited a specific campaign page.

For example,

Session 1: visitation to www.website.com/marketingpage

Session 2: the same user returns to literally any other page on the website www.website.com/anyotherpage

I know that GA will provide 'count of sessions' under the user explorer and 'average sessions per user', but i don't see any way of segmenting or reporting on user activity in a previous session.

Am i missing something? Is it possible?

To be clear I don't care about the identity of the user at all. Just the linkage between sessions

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by creating an "advanced segment" for the users that have visited that page:

- Visit a report that has the user count
- Click "+ Add Segment"
- Click on "+ New Segment"
- Name the segment "marketingpage visitors"
- Choose "Advanced conditions"
- Set it to "Filter Users Include Page /marketingpage"
- Save the segment
- Make sure it is the only segment currently applied (remove any other segments)
- View your report